# Живые деньги, в смысле наличные, пишутся в кавычках?

Tags: кавычки

Выражение «живые деньги», в смысле наличные, пишутся в кавычках?

Answer (score 3):

**Оба варианта встречаются почти с равной частотностью.** В текстах разговорной тематики обычно используется вариант без кавычек, но чем серьезнее издание, тем  чаще там можно встретить кавычки.

Провал системы софинансирования уже показал, что сберегать **«живые» деньги** на пенсию население не хочет, а в большинстве случаев и не может себе позволить. [Повестка дня // «Эксперт», 2015]

Так потекли первые **живые деньги** с рынка сотовой телефонии, и деньги немалые. [Геннадий Горелик. Наука и жизнь российского предпринимателя: Рождение дела // «Знание ― сила», 2003]

Если дать ей в руки **живые деньги**, она тут же побежит покупать что-нибудь для сестер и брата. [Александра Маринина. Иллюзия греха (1996)]

Answer (score 0):

Кавычки не требуются: выражение стало устойчивым, привычным.

По мере того как... выражения становятся обиходными, в кавычки они заключаются все реже. Например, стали писать без кавычек: *часы пик; голосовать за и против; работать на отлично; Большая восьмёрка* и др.
[Розенталь. Употребление кавычек](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=169)

[Словарь синонимов](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/43350/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5):

живые деньги

деньги, чистые деньги, звонкая монета, наличность, наличные, чистоган.

Answer (score 0):

В [**экономическом словаре**](http://abc.informbureau.com/html/ae_-_aeeaua_aaiuae.html) термин *живые деньги* приводится без кавычек:

ЖИВЫЕ ДЕНЬГИ — наличные деньги, выплачиваемые за проделанную работу, предоставленную услугу и проданную ценность...
(Сравните: "таможенная война" — в кавычках.)

Со словом "деньги" достаточно выражений, которые вошли в язык, широко используются и не требуют ни дополнительных объяснений, ни кавычек:
большие, сумасшедшие, бешеные, шальные деньги; плакали мои денежки; "У Павлинского всегда водилась вольная деньга" (Салтыков-Щедрин).

[Ориентироваться на "приличные" экономические обзоры, как мне кажется, тоже не стоит. В [**одной и той же статье**](https://www.gazeta.ru/business/2018/01/10/11604302.shtml?updated) вы можете увидеть оба варианта:
*В нем на начало года находилось 3,753 трлн рублей, но на **«живые деньги»** из этой суммы приходилось около половины.* (...)
*То есть **живых денег** в ФНБ около 2 трлн рублей*.]

Владислав Гинько (экономист, эксперт РАНХиГС при Президенте РФ, ведущий программы «Экономика по-русски») в своей статье (17.08.2016) "Правительство ищет **живые деньги** для пенсий" пишет:
*Средства из нашей кубышки и снижение цен — это два инструмента получения **живых денег** в экономике.*
(...) *благодаря росту того же сельского хозяйства мы будем получать **живые деньги**, за счёт которых можно будет поднимать пенсии.*

Думаю, что словосочетание *живые деньги* вполне грамотно использовать без кавычек (всем ведь понятно — о каких деньгах речь), а "ёлочки" оставить для особенных случаев, например, таких: **"Живые" деньги: разводим шмелей, бабочек, раков.**